# Flow rate and proportion

Tags: rate-of-convergence

I'm wondering if there is a short cut for calculating the time taken for 2taps to fill and another tap to empty a tank apart from the usual way.
          For e g. two taps take 20minutes to for fill a tank while another 30minutes to empty the tank .Calculate the time taken to fill the tank .please help with short cut

Comment: Arbitrarilly assign a volume to the tank that is convenient.  For a tank of a given size each tap has a flow rate of so many gallons per minute.  Calculate the net flow (just add what flows in subtract what flows out).  Find the number of minutes.  If you feel the need to be rigorous, show why your assumption of tank size ultimately has no bearing on the final answer.

Answer (score 0):

The filling rate is the difference in the flow rates. Input rate $(\frac{V}{20})$/min - output rate $(\frac{V}{30})$/min $= (\frac{V}{60})$/minute where $V$ is the volume of the tank. So the time taken will be 60 minutes.